# how we can add LWUIT in android application?

Tags: android, lwuit, netbeans6.5

i used netbeans 6.5 for developing android application. i need to add LWUIT for this application. how we can add into this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWUIT is a library that works on MIDP.

It is possible to get lwuit running on android through the use of the Activity class. Although no official port exists.

An official Blackberry port does exist. and instructions can be found here: http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/11/building-project-on-blackberry.html

Comment: Hi demian i successfully integrated LWUIT with android 2.2. Im using eclipse for this purpose. They created own Activity class for running the midlet application on android mobiles. :)

Comment: thanks, for correcting, i edited my post to reflect you comment.

Answer (score 3):

There already is (for quite a while now) a native LWUIT port for Android contributed by community member Thorsten Schemm with instructions here:
http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html

This port is fully open source under the same license as LWUIT and available in the LWUIT incubator project here:
http://lwuit-incubator.java.net/

There are several commercial applications deployed based on this port to Android, it allows creating an Activity and binding it just like any other activity.

Answer (score 2):

Android has its own UI library, concept and lifecycle. 
It is completely different to the MDIP UI concept.

To use LWUIT, it has to be ported to Android.

Also see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: Hi, thanks.. can u tel me the brief how to configure with android ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand your question. I don't know the internals of LWUIT, but I think most of the code has to be rewritten. In my oppinion that doesn't make much sense. You better start getting used to the Android GUI workflow. If your app is well designed you should only need to rewrite the UI Part of your mobile application.